# how to determine process on other end of named pipe

Tags: windows

I need to determine what process is on the other end of a named pipe.  Experimenting with ProcessExplorer and some SysInternals executables (e.g. pipelist, handles) show me the creator/owner of the pipe only.

Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the [`GetNamedPipeClientProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365440%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and/or [`GetNamedPipeServerProcessId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365446%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions.